# Get list of data types from schema in Apache Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, types, schema, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code in Spark-Python to get the list of names from the schema of a DataFrame, which works fine, but how can I get the list of the data types?

```
columnNames = df.schema.names
```

For example, something like:

```
columnTypes = df.schema.types
```

Is there any way to get a separate list of the data types contained in a DataFrame schema?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a', 1)])

types = [f.dataType for f in df.schema.fields]

types
> [StringType, LongType]
```

Reference:

- [pyspark.sql.types.StructType](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructType)
- [pyspark.sql.types.StructField](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.StructField)

Comment: or `df.printSchema()`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'printSchema'`

Answer (score 18):

Since the question title is not python-specific, I'll add `scala` version here:

```
val types = df.schema.fields.map(f => f.dataType)
```

It will result in an array of `org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType`.

Comment: the tags include python though

Comment: Still quite helpful for people who land here who happen to using scala though.

Answer (score 3):

Use schema.dtypes

```
scala> val df = Seq(("ABC",10,20.4)).toDF("a","b","c")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: string, b: int ... 1 more field]

scala>

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- b: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- c: double (nullable = false)

scala> df.dtypes
res2: Array[(String, String)] = Array((a,StringType), (b,IntegerType), (c,DoubleType))

scala> df.dtypes.map(_._2).toSet
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType)

scala>
```