# python- get column dataType from a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get a column data type from a dataframe

Here is a sample code:

```
    print training_data.schema
    print 'fields'
    print training_data.schema.fields
    print 'names'
    print training_data.schema.names
```

The above code prints as shown below:
StructType(List(StructField(id,LongType,true),StructField(text,StringType,true),StructField(label,DoubleType,true)))
fields
[StructField(id,LongType,true), StructField(text,StringType,true), StructField(label,DoubleType,true)]
names
['id', 'text', 'label']

But how can I get the datatype for label column ? Thanks a lot for your time.

Regards

Comment: check this,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335307/get-list-of-data-types-from-schema-in-apache-spark

Answer (score 1):

```
df['col label'].dtype
```

Is one option.

*Edit*

```
name_dtype = df['col label'].dtype.name
```

Comment: I tried this, but it prints: Column<label['dtype']>

Comment: tried, it prints <bound method Column.alias of Column<label['dtype']>>

Comment: Oops, I think we might be talking about different dataframes. My answer was with regards to Pandas dataframes and not SQL dataframes. My bad. If you have Pandas installed, you could always convert your SQL dataframe to a Pandas dataframe and try my solution.

Comment: oh,ok I will try that. Sorry I am new to this python. What is the difference between SQL dataframe and pandas dataframe?

Comment: How do I get the data type in SQL dataframe?

Comment: I've actually never used pyspark hehe so I don't want to speak for pyspark dataframes. In Pandas however, a dataframe is just a tabular data structure. And I know that one can convert between Pandas dataframes and pyspark SQL dataframes. It's best someone else answer the remainder of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is copy-paste example of how to get column names and colum types for pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

list = [['Tom',34, 45.5], ['Jack',23, 60.5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns=["Name","Age","Pay"])

for column in df.columns:
    print("Column ", column, "is dtype:", df[column].dtype.name)
```

result:

```
Column  Name is dtype: object
Column  Age is dtype: int64
Column  Pay is dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses.
I found the below solution, hoping it will be helpful to any one looking for the answer:

```
       for f, v in zip(df.schema.fields, df.schema.names):
          if v == colname:
            datatype = f.dataType
```